# Login to IIS Website from LAN PC

Tags: c#, session, iis, networking, iis-7.5

I have a local IIS Website. I can access it locally. However, when I try to login from the LAN computer, I cannot sign in. I can browser the site, but not logging in does not work. The login code return true; however, it seems like IIS does not keep a session for Local computer.

I am running IIS 7.5. I think I miss an IIS setup or installation somewhere.

Have any of you ran to this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. In the Web Config, I have set it to only allow form and cookies from a certain domain. When removing that, it works